# Debugging an IE(7) plugin (BHO)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer

When I start debugging my IE7 BHO, I often have a strange case where IE 'hangs' and doesn't load its homepage for at least 3min (and probably never). IE itself is responsive (menus, min/max, close etc.) but even attempting to navigate also gives infinite load times.

This happens in debug mode via VS2008, but not in release mode when the plugin is actually installed on the machine. I think it also doesn't happen when debug mode is installed, but I'm not sure.

Anyone encountered this strange phenomena and might have an idea?

Edit: Here are the few last lineof my console from when its stuck. When its not stuck, it flows past imageres and continues to other modules in seconds:

'iexplore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\credssp.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

'iexplore.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\credssp.dll'

'iexplore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SensApi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

'iexplore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\credssp.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

'iexplore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\schannel.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x15d4) has exited with code 12004 (0x2ee4).

'iexplore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll'

'iexplore.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll'`

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your development environment is busy downloading symbols for all of IE's DLLs, but that's just a guess.

Comment: That problem still can be intermittent depending on symbol caching.

However, which version of Windows are you using? What is your startup page URL/Zone in the test scenario? You might be crossing integrity levels on startup, and that in turn might confuse the debugger.

Comment: I assume my symbol cache doesn't change much, certainly not between two runs one after the other (one works the second not). I'm using IE7 on Vista Home Premium 32bit.

My startup page is my test server (Tomcat, waiting for connections on 8080), I'll try changing it and see if it has effect.